# Converting dynamic JOINS to SQL statements

Tags: sql

I need an idea to transform the following "If's" conditions to a raw SQL statement. (No Dynamic SQL)

```
Dim strVar1 as String, strVar2 as String, strVar3 as String, intSet Int32

.Append("SELECT * FROM TABLE_A as A ")
.Append("INNER JOIN TABLE_B as B ON A.Code=B.Code_A ")

If strVar1.Length > 0 Then
  .Append("LEFT JOIN TABLE_C as C ON C.Code=A.Code_C ")
  .Append("LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_D as D on C.Code=D.Code_C AND D.Col1 IN (1,NULL) ")
End If

If strVar2.Length > 0 Or strVar3.Length > 0 Then
  .Append("LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_E as E ON A.Code=E.Code_A ")
  .Append("LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_F as F ON E.Col1=F.Col1 ")
  .Append("INNER JOIN TABLE_G ON as G ON F.Code=G.Code_F AND G.Col1=1 ")
End If

Select Case intType
    Case 1 , 2    
       If intSet <> -1 Then
         .Append("LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_H H on A.code=H.code_A AND H.code_H=1 AND H.Pos=1 ")
       Else
         .Append("LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_H H on A.code=H.code_A AND H.Pos=1 ")
       End If
    Case 3 , 4
End Select
```

Comment: Where does intSet come from? Where is the "With" for the .Append statments?

Comment: Just a remark. The `D.Col1 IN (1,NULL)` should be `(D.Col1 = 1 OR D.Col1 IS NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

You may try WHEN THEN SQL constructs!
Logic: All joins will be there. However if you want to join based on some condition, put cross table column in join clause else the same table column
Something like:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_A.* FROM TABLE_A as A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B as B ON A.Code=B.Code_A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_C as C ON C.Code=
    CASE WHEN LEN(@strVar1)>0
    THEN
    A.Code_C -- join with your table
    ELSE
    C.Code -- join with itself to do nothing
    END
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_D as D on C.Code=
    CASE WHEN LEN(@strVar1)>0 THEN
    D.Code_C AND D.Col1 IN (1,null)
    ELSE
    C.Code
    END
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's easy, or even possible, to transform your dynamic sql code into a single sql query with parameters. I have the feeling the only solution would be to create one query for each combination of values you use in your tests. That's a lot of queries: 16 if I counted correctly.

If your goal is to speedup your query, I'm pretty sure this would help: execution plan won't need to be calculated each time. But this comes at the price of more complicated code.